# Assay for Glycosyltransferase

Tags: enzymes, synthetic-biology, enzyme-kinetics

I want to do an assay to see, if an ordered enzyme is active or not. It's a glucosyltransferase from S. mutans which hydrolyses sucrose into fructose and glucose. It then connects the glucose-monomers to dextran. Our idea is to detect the free fructose. There are many tests for this, for example the Fehling-Test or the Tollen-Test. The trouble is, that they have to be heated on a waterbath - I think that's very suitable for microwell-plates. Maybe someone here has a better idea how to measure the enzyme's activity?

Comment: If you've access to a PCR machine or a heating plate with a microplate with a heating block you can use that

Comment: There are indirect enzymatic assays to detect fructose based on NADH production by glycolytic enzymes.

Comment: Yes, true, but they are very expensive (about 400 Euro). 
Thanks for the answers, but we now sticked in to a new method with 3,5-dinitrosalicylic acid (photometrically), which also detects free fructose.

Comment: What about this kit? http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/fa20